# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS won't shutdown or restart

Tags: boot, kernel, shutdown, restart

I'm new Ubuntu user"2 days old" ,I want to say that it is magnificent but there is a tiny problem that bothers me a lot.
When I shut down or restart it stuck up in a black screen and stays there until I forcibly turn it off.
I have tried to upgrade mainline kernel to 4.8.15 and I thought the problem is solved because now it shows Ubuntu's logo but sadly it stuck up at this point and I shut it down forcibly.
So any ideas about solving this problem ?
Thank you

Comment: Does this problem occur while shutting down through terminal ?

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs even while shutting down through terminal ... I tried this as a solution but it didn't work

and I tried this and it didn't work
I changed the line in /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
and then ran 
sudo grub-update

Answer (score 1):

I also has this problem. but it's solved, when i replace my **kernal to 4.4.15**.

link for [kernal 4.4.15](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.15/)

- download the link on it.
- if your computer is 64 bit download first 4 link.
- and extract to a specific folder.
- open a terminal from there.
- and write the code.

  sudo dpkg -i *.deb

that's all.....